# Steenrod squares in a Puppe sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration, cohomology-operations

Consider the following Puppe sequence.
$$\cdots\to K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},2)\to \Omega X\to K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},1)\stackrel{a}{\to} K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},3)\to X\to K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},2)\stackrel{b}{\to} K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},4)\to \cdots$$
If $b=\mathrm{Sq}^2$, the stability of the Steenrod square implies $a=\mathrm{Sq}^2$.
However, this seems inconsistent to me because $b$ is not trivial but $a$ is trivial.
Namely, we have $\Omega X\simeq K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},2)\times K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},1)$ but $X\not\simeq K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},3)\times K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},2)$, which looks inconsistent.

**Question:** I must have made stupid mistakes somewhere. Could anyone help me to figure it out?

Comment: Why do you think that looks inconsistent?

Comment: @Tyrone I think $\Omega (X\times Y)\simeq \Omega X\times \Omega Y$.

Comment: That certainly holds. It is still possible that $\Omega Z\simeq \Omega X\times \Omega Y$ without $Z$ being homotopy equivalent to $X\times Y$.

Comment: @Tyrone I think the delooping of a deloopable space is unique (up to weak homotopy equivalence). So $Z$ and $X\times Y$ should be equivalent if both of them are connected.

Comment: You have a perfectly good counterexample to that thought above.

Comment: @Tyrone Oh I see. Thank you very much! Besides, does it mean there are two inequivalent $A_{\infty}$-space structures on $K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},2)\times K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},1)$?

Comment: It seems to me that there is a natural unital multiplication $(H^2(-) \otimes H^1(-)) \otimes (H^2(-) \otimes H^1(-) ) \rightarrow H^2(-) \otimes H^1(-)$ given by $(a_0,b_0)\otimes(a_1,b_1)\rightarrow (a_0+a_1+b_0b_1,b_0+b_1)$ which should lead to an "exotic" $A_\infty$ structure with a little effort.

Comment: @ConnorMalin That's perfect! Thank you!